# brew failed to start jenkins with Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl enable gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts` exited with 64

Tags: macos, jenkins

brew services start jenkins-lts is failing with
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl enable gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts` exited with 64.

Please advise